# Enthought Canopy GUI won't open

Tags: enthought, canopy

I've downloaded Enthought Canopy Express onto my 64-bit Windows 10 laptop, but when I try to open the Canopy program it won't open.

If I try to open it from the desktop shortcut or go into the program files and try to open it directly from the .exe file, all it will do is show the splash page, which then disappears after showing for a few seconds, and then nothing happens. Also after the splash page is gone, task manager shows that Canopy isn't running.

The PyLab application will open and works fine, but I need the actual Enthought Canopy application to work for a class I'm taking.

When I installed it for the very first time, it did open and I was able to use the Enthought Canopy application, but ever since I closed out of it since then it hasn't worked.

When I go into the program files to try and open it from the .exe file, for the file Canopy.exe it will open the splash page and then close, and for Canopy_cli.exe it will open a command prompt looking window, then the splash page, and then both close. The file _python.exe will open and work, and the file _pythonw.exe does nothing.
(These files are at C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App if that makes any difference.)

I've uninstalled and restarted and reinstalled several times, and I've tried the "Full Reset" suggested in [this article](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469700-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy). My user name is just "charizard" and my computer name is "messier42", so the problem isn't that it's a non-ASCII user name.

I have also tried the test to see if it's a problem with the PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME environment variables like it suggests in [this article](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469810-Windows-Canopy-shortcut-in-Start-menu-doesn-t-do-anything), but it didn't start Canopy.
This is what I got from the command prompt when I tested that:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\charizard>
C:\Users\charizard>set pythonpath=

C:\Users\charizard>set pythonhome=

C:\Users\charizard>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Roaming
asl.log=Destination=file
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=MESSIER42
ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\charizard
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\MicrosoftAccount
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Acer\Remote Files\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;c:\users\charizard\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\scripts;C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\3.5.2.91395\bin\Firefox_Extension\{442718d9-475e-452a-b3e1-fb1ee16b8e9f}\components;C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User;C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=4501
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
TEMP=C:\Users\CHARIZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\CHARIZ~1\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=MESSIER42
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=MESSIER42
USERNAME=charizard
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\charizard
windir=C:\WINDOWS
```

[.... later after correcting typo...]

```
C:\Users\charizard>cd "%localappdata%\enthought\canopy\app"

C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App>_python.exe canopy-script.pyw
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "canopy-script.pyw", line 776, in <module>

  File "canopy-script.pyw", line 336, in bootstrap

  File "canopy-script.pyw", line 363, in chainload

  File "canopy-script.pyw", line 762, in _chainload

  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\Canopy-script.pyw", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 2421, in main
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\bootstrap.py", line 2357, in send_bug_report
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\application.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\envisage\ui\tasks\api.py", line 2, in <module>
from preferences_pane import PreferencesPane
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\envisage\ui\tasks\preferences_pane.py", line 4, in <module>
from traitsui.api import Controller
   File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\traitsui\api.py", line 41, in <module>
from .editors.api import (BooleanEditor, ButtonEditor,
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from .api import (toolkit, BooleanEditor, ButtonEditor,
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\api.py", line 8, in <module>
from .array_editor import ArrayEditor
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\traitsui\editors\array_editor.py", line 27, in <module>
import numpy
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 185, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
from . import scimath as emath
ImportError: cannot import name scimath

C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App>
C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App>Uncaught exception captured
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\main.py", line 53, in main
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\application_launcher.py", line 350, in launch
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\application.py", line 361, in run
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\ui\tasks\tasks_application.py", line 131, in run
started = self.start()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\application.py", line 295, in start
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\application.py", line 295, in start
self.plugin_manager.start()
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\app\canopy_plugin_manager.py", line 140, in start
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\composite_plugin_manager.py", line 133, in start
self.start_plugin(plugin)
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\composite_plugin_manager.py", line 143, in start_plugin
plugin.activator.start_plugin(plugin)
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\plugin_activator.py", line 30, in start_plugin
plugin.start()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/canopy_data_import_addon/plugin.py", line 79, in start
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\application.py", line 370, in get_service
protocol, query, minimize, maximize
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\service_registry.py", line 77, in get_service
services = self.get_services(protocol, query, minimize, maximize)
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\service_registry.py", line 114, in get_services
actual_protocol, name, obj, properties, service_id
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\service_registry.py", line 258, in _resolve_factory
obj = obj(**properties)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\plugin\plugin.py", line 183, in _create_package_manager_service
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\application.py", line 370, in get_service
protocol, query, minimize, maximize
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\service_registry.py", line 77, in get_service
services = self.get_services(protocol, query, minimize, maximize)
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\service_registry.py", line 114, in get_services
actual_protocol, name, obj, properties, service_id
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\service_registry.py", line 258, in _resolve_factory
obj = obj(**properties)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\accounts\plugin.py", line 69, in _create_account_service
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\accounts\account_service.py", line 359, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py", line 3285, in _init_trait_listeners
getattr( self, '_init_trait_%s_listener' % data[0] )( name, *data )
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py", line 3340, in _init_trait_delegate_listener
self.on_trait_change( notify, name_pattern, target=self )
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py", line 2584, in on_trait_change
listener.register( self )
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\traits_listener.py", line 433, in register
value = getattr( self, type )( new, name, False )
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\traits_listener.py", line 701, in _register_simple
return next.register( getattr( object, name ) )
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\accounts\account_service.py", line 308, in _preferences_default
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\accounts\account_service.py", line 314, in _enstaller_config_default
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\enstaller\config.py", line 299, in from_file
    ret = _create(fp)
    File    "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\enstaller\config.py", line 268, in _create
    parsed = parse_assignments(fp)
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\egginst\utils.py", line 207, in parse_assignments
return _AssignmentParser().parse(file_or_filename.read())
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\egginst\utils.py", line 172, in parse
root = ast.parse(s)
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes
Exception occurred in traits notification handler.
Please check the log file for details.
Exception occurred in traits notification handler for object: <canopy.logging.logging_service.LoggingService object at 0x00000000054EAA98>, trait: exception_added, old value: <undefined>, new value: <LogRecord: root, 40, build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\logging\logging_service.py, 154, "Uncaught exception captured">
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\trait_notifiers.py", line 340, in __call__
self.handler( *args )
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\logging\logging_service.py", line 203, in _exception_added_fired
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\logging\logging_service.py", line 187, in _report_exception
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter.py", line 505, in start
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter_view.py", line 192, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter_view.py", line 221, in setup_ui
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter_view.py", line 304, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter.py", line 269, in _requester_email_default
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter.py", line 261, in _account_service_default
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\accounts\account_service.py", line 359, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py", line 3285, in _init_trait_listeners
getattr( self, '_init_trait_%s_listener' % data[0] )( name, *data )
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py", line 3340, in _init_trait_delegate_listener
self.on_trait_change( notify, name_pattern, target=self )
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py", line 2584, in on_trait_change
listener.register( self )
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\traits_listener.py", line 433, in register
value = getattr( self, type )( new, name, False )
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\traits_listener.py", line 701, in _register_simple
return next.register( getattr( object, name ) )
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\accounts\account_service.py", line 308, in _preferences_default
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\accounts\account_service.py", line 314, in _enstaller_config_default
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\enstaller\config.py", line 299, in from_file
ret = _create(fp)
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\enstaller\config.py", line 268, in _create
parsed = parse_assignments(fp)
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\egginst\utils.py", line 207, in parse_assignments
return _AssignmentParser().parse(file_or_filename.read())
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\egginst\utils.py", line 172, in parse
root = ast.parse(s)
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes
Exception occurred in traits notification handler for object: <canopy.logging.logging_service.LoggingService object at 0x00000000054EAA98>, trait: exception_added, old value: <undefined>, new value: <LogRecord: root, 40, build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\logging\logging_service.py, 154, "Uncaught exception captured">
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\trait_notifiers.py", line 340, in __call__
self.handler( *args )
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\logging\logging_service.py", line 203, in _exception_added_fired
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\logging\logging_service.py", line 187, in _report_exception
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter.py", line 505, in start
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter_view.py", line 192, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter_view.py", line 221, in setup_ui
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter_view.py", line 304, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter.py", line 269, in _requester_email_default
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\feedback\data_reporter.py", line 261, in _account_service_default
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\accounts\account_service.py", line 359, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py", line 3285, in _init_trait_listeners
getattr( self, '_init_trait_%s_listener' % data[0] )( name, *data )
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py", line 3340, in _init_trait_delegate_listener
self.on_trait_change( notify, name_pattern, target=self )
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py", line 2584, in on_trait_change
listener.register( self )
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\traits_listener.py", line 433, in register
value = getattr( self, type )( new, name, False )
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\traits_listener.py", line 701, in _register_simple
return next.register( getattr( object, name ) )
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\accounts\account_service.py", line 308, in _preferences_default
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy\accounts\account_service.py", line 314, in _enstaller_config_default
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\enstaller\config.py", line 299, in from_file
ret = _create(fp)
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\enstaller\config.py", line 268, in _create
parsed = parse_assignments(fp)
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\egginst\utils.py", line 207, in parse_assignments
return _AssignmentParser().parse(file_or_filename.read())
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\egginst\utils.py", line 172, in parse
root = ast.parse(s)
  File "C:\Users\charizard\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes
```

Comment: In your `cd` command, `canopy64` should just be `canopy` (look back at the article). This won't solve the problem, but it might provide more info.

Comment: When you say you've restarted, do you mean that you've restarted your system, or just Canopy?

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party anti-virus application? If so, try disabling it (you'll still be protected by MSoft's very capable virus software) immediately after restarting Windows, before doing a full reset.

Comment: When I say restarted, I mean I turned off my computer and turned it back on again after uninstalling it. I do have a couple  3rd party anti-virus applications, I'll try what you suggested!

Comment: I tried uninstalling my 3rd party anti-virus applications (McAfee and Malwarebytes) and doing a full reset and restarting and reinstalling, but the same problem is still happening.

Comment: you have not yet corrected the `canopy64` and shown the output from the corrected sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please zip and email your file `C:\Users\charizard\.enstaller4rc` to support@enthought.com for forensics, and refer to this SO article. Then just delete that file, and I expect that you'll be able to start Canopy ok.

Comment: I sent the email and deleted the file, and now it's running correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Next step:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: This discussion was 2 years ago. Problems with .enstaller4rc are much less likely in recent Canopy versions. The current version of Canopy is 2.1.3